# Using TO-92 package for high voltage applications

Tags: transistors, high-voltage, pcb-assembly

I'm looking to build a high voltage (but low current) current source and I see transistors rated at 500V in a TO-92 package. The leads aren't even bent so spaced 50mils/1.27mm apart, and when measuring the corresponding footprint pad spacing in KiCAD it is below the safe distance for an external pcb trace at that voltage:

[image: to-92 footprint]

According to KiCAD electrical spacing calculator, for voltages over 500V, uncoated pads and lead terminations should be no less than 1.805mm apart, so even the leads of the package itself are too close according to this (about 0.85mm free space between the leads).

I must be missing something, if they make HV parts in this package there must be a way to safely implement them but I can't find guidelines or best practices on this even on the manufacturers' sites. I'm still searching but would appreciate pointers and/or links to documents.

Example of such a HV TO-92 part: [ZTX560 datasheet](https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/ZTX560.pdf).

**Edit**
From the answers and comments, I switched to using the TO-92 "wide" footprint from kiCAD for voltages over 15 volts. For straight pin TO-92 parts this involves some fancy lead twisting for the outer pins to reach their holes but this will make for safer designs. Conformal coatings might still be needed on the pins for very high voltages over 400V.

[image: TO-92 wide footprint example usage]

Comment: Almost all the time one would use a transistor well below its maximum ratings.

Comment: NEVER use a part at its rated voltage or current. That is asking for trouble, so keep spare parts on hand. Try not to run them more than 75% of rated values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> According to kiCAD electrical spacing calculator, for voltages over
> 500V, uncoated pads and lead terminations should be no less than
> 1.805mm apart,

The keyword here is **"uncoated"**. Therefore, to use this device at its max (which should be never the case), you MUST use conformal coating over traces and the device itself. According to [this calculator](https://www.smps.us/pcbtracespacing.html), coated traces/wires can be 0.8 mm apart to hold 500V.

Comment: The TO-92 transistor is the reference for a larger TO-220 in a Vbe current source for a tube amp power supply. It will see a maximum of 440V for a short period of less than a second until the output capacitors are charged, then in steady state will see between 70 and 200V. So if I use say a transistor rated 600V, 75% of which gives 450V I should be clear with the bent-lead configuration suggested by Spehro above and conformal coating on the leads where they come close together?

Comment: @Joe, people usually use bigger packages like TO-247 for high-voltage application, with 5mm pin pitch, and no such questions arise.

Comment: Yes of course I was just curious when I saw HV parts in small package :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can't really do anything about the creepage on the package except add conformal coating (which is sometimes done, even in consumer products).

As far as the PCB goes, you can use a footprint designed for formed leads, and this is a good idea even if the voltages are not a concern, for purely mechanical reasons - think of the extreme forces that could be placed on the package from differential thermal expansion, especially following wave (or other) soldering if the exposed part of the leads was extremely short.

[Here](https://forum.kicad.info/t/jlcpcb-hasl-bridges-on-the-default-transistor-footprint/22394/10) is a typical Kicad footprint that may be suitable:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Spehro for your reply. So it's do-able with careful attention to creepage clearance and some conformal coating if pushes comes to shove. That being said this might be the "push" that makes me switch to SMD technology - readily available parts in DPAK seem more suited for HV with larger lead spacing and I think I could solder them manually with a fine iron tip... What do you think?

Comment: Sounds like a good move to me. TO-252s are really easy to solder by hand though you need reasonably powerful iron to get the tab soldered quickly and it would be better if it is controlled temperature.

Comment: The TO-92 parts are usually quite a bit cheaper, and smaller which is why you'll see high voltage TO-92 parts like high-voltage BJTs and [similar devices](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/2304140030_Wuxi-China-Resources-Huajing-Microelectronics-3DD13003E1D_C162349.pdf), [SCRs](https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/S08xxA-SERIES.pdf) and [triacs](https://www.ween-semi.com/sites/default/files/2018-10/z0103ma.pdf)  in mains lamp switching power supplies, ignition controllers and that sort of consumer product. If you're not pinching pennies and have the space better to use bigger parts.

Comment: What is that 3DD13003 E1D part, says BJT transistor but I've never seen such a funky NPN with a PNP across its base-emitter junction... Protective measure? What's more confusing is some datasheet show a regular NPN symbol for it...

Comment: @Joe It's clamped so it switches quickly. It was used in CFL lamps by the billions.

Comment: Machine translation of the blurb on the front page: "The product adopts plane technology and pressure dividing ring
Terminal structure and minority carrier lifetime control
technology, integrating active anti-saturation network
network, which improves the breakdown voltage of the product
voltage, switching speed and reliability."  Probably "planar technology" and "guard ring" would be more idiomatic translations.

Comment: Thanks for that, my mandarin is a bit rusty (err... non-existent ;-) Depressing to think that this bulb on the ceiling is more technologically advanced than my projects but hey - got to start at the beginning!

Answer (score 1):

Several considerations:

- Creepage and clearance aren't functionally required.  They are required in many cases -- but actual electrical breakdown in clean conditions can be quite high, and FUNCTIONAL type insulation is acceptable in specific cases.
- Package material is (or... can be? I'm not too clear on it myself, but asking the manufacturer would be prudent) higher CTI (comparative tracking index) than ordinary plastics and resins, so doesn't need as much distance as you might expect.  Typical molding compounds are mostly (like 80%+?) silica, so they don't char as much, or as thoroughly, as you'd expect from other materials.  This also gives higher strength and lower expansion rate, critical for operating temperature and longevity.
- You aren't required to use the package pin spacing; pins can be formed by hand, with a tool, or ordered with spread or staggered pins.  This greatly increases the pad-pad spacing.
- You can also rout slots in the board, at least when pad spacings are sufficient to do so.  You often see this on stagger-legged TO-220s for SMPS application, for example.